# How to Validate mathematical formula expressions using regex

Tags: .net, regex

I am looking for mathematical formula validation using regex.
Here is the example code that I am using:-

```
 string equation = "(a+b)*10";

 bool b = false;

 Regex rx = new Regex(@"^((?<o1>[^-+*/()]+|\([^-+*/()]+\)|(?<p>\()+[^-+*/()]+|[^-+*/()]+(?<-p>\)))[-+*/])+(?<o2>[^-+*/()]+|\([^-+*/()]+\)|(?<p>\()+[^-+*/()]+|[^-+*/()]+(?<-p>\)))(?(p)(?!))$");

 if (rx.IsMatch(equation))
     {
      b = true;
     }
```

It is working fine with the expression used Like "(a+b)*100". I mean If I go for wrong placement of braces like "(a+b))*100" or "(a+b*100" or "(a+b)*100)" it is doing perfect validation. But if go for introduction of my user defined functions like "Sum(1,2)" or Sqrt(8) It is failing to validate.

I want this to validate my functions also. Like "Sum(1,2)","Sum(1,2" ,"Sum1,2)", "Sum(1,2))". I mean it should take care of proper usage of braces.

Note:- I am using ANTLR to create these funations.

Thanks

Comment: Mathematical expressions are not a regular grammar and cannot be parsed using regular expressions

Comment: Which language are you running that regex in?

Answer (score 0):

A generic mathematical formula would be too complex to parse using a regular expression.  Use ANTLR to write a grammar that can parse out the individual elements instead.

Comment: can you provide me some link from where I could get reference of how to write this type of validation. I've tried to search many options but things are not satisfactory.

Comment: Well your best bet is to purchase The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference, as writing grammars isn't the simplest thing in the world.  However, if you can't do that then in the source code for the book available at http://media.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/code/tpantlr2-code.tgz there is a grammar in `tour/ActionExpr.g4` which has a similar grammar to the one which you are attempting to parse.